# Strict aliasing and __m128i type

Tags: c++, c, sse2

When using SSE2 intrinsic functions to do bit-wise operations, one has to cast pointers from `int*` to `__m128i*`. Does this code break strict aliasing rule?

```
void bit_twiddling_func(int size, int const* input, int* output) {
    const __m128* x = (const __m128*)input;
    const __m128* y = (const __m128*)output;

    for (int i=0; i < size/4; ++i, ++x, ++y) {
        __m128i x4 = _mm_load_si128(x); // load 4 integers

        // do some bit twiddling

        _mm_store_si128(y, x4); // store 4 integers
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have to use `int*` pointers?  Why can't you just make `bit_twiddling_func` accept `__m128*` parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; it breaks strict aliasing rules.  Two different types can't point to the same location in memory.  Here you have x pointing to input and y pointing to output, but they're of differing types.

You could change the signature of your function to take __m128* parameters, but it's probably easiest to leave it be.  It'll likely work just fine if you're careful that the input/output arguments point to memory with the proper alignment and size constraints  (i.e. they should each point to something where your loop doesn't index off the end or load uninitialized data.)

Comment: Technically it only breaks the strict aliasing rules when the type is actually accessed through the pointer, not when the pointer is created - so in this case it would be within `_mm_load_si128()`.

Comment: Technically it also only breaks strict aliasing rules when in C99 -- C89 and C++ do not have such restrictions.

Comment: @Billy: both C89 and C++ have those restrictions.

Comment: @zvrba: Can you find a reference then? I don't see any such restrictions in my copy of the standard. The word "alias" is used only to refer to namespace aliases. The word "pun" (e.g. type punning) exists only as a part of the word "punct". It's also not mentioned during the discussion of the casting operators.

Comment: The following PDF has a citation and a reference to the standard: http://dbp-consulting.com/StrictAliasing.pdf ; the relevant section is 6.5 Expressions.